# Unix custom sorting

Tags: sorting, unix

Hi I want to sort my file output using custom sort please help me.

Input File.

```
USA|123|Pin
UK|1243|Pin
Australia|555|Pin
Germany|1|Pin
Singapore|65|Pin
Germany|10|Pin
```

Here I want to show Row contains Germany in first position and rest of rows n same order as in file.

Output >>

```
Germany|1|Pin
Germany|10|Pin
USA|123|Pin
UK|1243|Pin
Australia|555|Pin
Singapore|65|Pin
```

Comment: Using what? Only *NIX command line tools?

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough with two passes through the file.

```
grep '^Germany|' originalfile >newfile
grep -v '^Germany|' originalfile >>newfile
```